# Alert role in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp with roles like this

```
 <div class="col-md-1 form-group inner-addon left-addon">
    <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${role == 'Incident Incharge' || role == 'Incident DeptHead' || role == 'Incident User'}">

           <input type="text" id="empName" name="empName" data-val="${list.empName}" value="${list.empName}" autocomplete="off"  /> 
            <input type="hidden" id="uempId" name="uempId" data-val="${list.uempId}" value="${list.uempId}" autocomplete="off"  /> 

          </p>

      </c:when>
   </c:choose>
```

How to alert the role in my script like

```
 <script>
    if(role=='Incident Incharge')
         {
             alert(role)
         }
 </script>
```

Comment: please try accessing like this, var role = '${role}';

Comment: Gurkan is right, I would just like to add that the key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed: JSP on the server, when the page is generated, Javascript in the browser, **after** the JSP code has finished its work. I.e. Javascript has no direct access to JSP variables, you have to pass them the way Gurkan showed.